# DT Package Buttons Extension (Download as PDF)

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a problem with *DT Buttons Extenstion* in *DT development version (0.1.56)* while downloading the table as PDF (the table is cut).

My original table consists of many columns – > that's why printing as PDF is going terribly wrong and half of the table is cut.

I was thinking maybe querformat would help or anyone could have a better idea?

Here is a sample code, which will demonstrate exactly same problem:

```
library("shiny")
library("DT")

data <- cbind(iris,iris,iris)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(
      data,extensions="Buttons",options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip',
                                               buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print')
      ))
  }
    )
```